# black screen under transition swift animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code, when I open the new screen, the old screen turn to black screen
I need that no have that black screen, just like defualt navigation that is like gray color, thanks

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 1.0
transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

[video](https://streamable.com/o033d)

the last part on the top

Comment: Try different presentation types/styles. Some replace the view controller, some `pop-over` it (which is probably what you want, rather than `modal`).

Comment: Also a short gif or video might help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this transition to view.layer, not to window.layer. It fix your problem